# Django createsuperuser command not working after switching from username to email

Tags: django, django-models

So I changed the Django username field to 'email', which is documented as completely legal [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD), but after this, the `createsuperuser` method doesn't work. Of cause I have added the Auth model to my settings and it worked before. This is basically my model currently:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

After migrating the change `createsuperuser` throws this after every input is entered:

```
XXX\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
```

I tried moving around this with a custom manager, but it threw new problems plus I would really would like to avoid this. Furthermore, I looked at the source code of the method, but couldn't figure out where this could go wrong. I also reset and deleted the database without luck.

Comment: Have you tried removing `username = None`?

Comment: Initially we did this with `username = models.CharField(unique=False, default=None, null=True)` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

It is happening because you should've overridden user model manager since you've changed the username field. For instance:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email, and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

And I think using this manager as your default manager  will solve your problem. Because the default manager always looks for username field when it's creating a new instance. So you should also change your model like following:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    objects = UserManager()  # use the above manager here 

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

I hope this will solve your problem.